# Outlook 2013 html email image get cut off half way

Tags: html, outlook

I have a html email the issue the image below gets cut off  half way in outlook 2013 only, I would expect this issue to occur in outlook 2007 but no outook is the only emailo cleint I can see where this issue occurs.

Could someone tell me how to fix it.

```
<table width="160" align="right" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="140" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="auto" align="right" valign="middle" height="70"  style=" font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align:center;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300;">
                                <a href="#" style="display: block !important;">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/140x40" width="137" height="40" alt="" style="max-width:100%; display:block;" border="0" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for browser/email client support and supported html css elements at http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Well you pointed in the right direction but had a look around After reading an article on campaign manager outlook 2013 does not respect height attribute if line-height is not set to at least 1